# Change the size of table or fix its position depending on screen size

Tags: bootstrap-4, frontend, responsive, bootstrap-table, screen-size

I have this table that looks like this:

[image]

However, when the screensize is reduced, the table will get closer to the right of the browser:

[image]

Breaking the footer, moving away from the right:

[image]

I've noticed this happens when I have a four column.

I guess two solutions would be decreasing the size of the table, and the other one center the table, but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that using bootstrap tables by itself won't be responsive. However, if we use the class `.table-responsive`, the table will be responsive and that will solve the issue.

The usage is simply setting an outer div:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="table">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```